# Use QProcess to only zcat as many lines as needed?

Tags: c++, linux, file, qt

In Linux if I run this command

```
zcat bigFile | head
```

Then `zcat` will not decompress all of `bigFile`, only as much as it needs to in order to supply `head` with the data it needs.

But what about this

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
process->start("zcat bigFile");
process->readLine();
QTimer::singleShot(10000, process, SLOT(terminate()));
```

Will the `zcat` command that is run in `process` only decompress whatever is needed for `readLine()`? Or will it continuously `zcat bigFile` for 10 seconds?

Is it possible to use a `QProcess` similarly to the Linux pipe `|`, and thus only `zcat` as many lines as have been requested?

Answer (score 1):

> Will the `zcat` command that is run in process only decompress whatever
>   is needed for `readLine()`?

### No

> Or will it continuously `zcat bigFile` for 10 seconds?

### Yes

To verify this, I wrote the following code

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
process->start("yes");

connect(process, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(_end()));
connect(process, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)), this, SLOT(_end()));

QByteArray byteArray = process->readLine(5);
QString line = QString(byteArray);

process->closeReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);

QTimer::singleShot(5000, process, SLOT(terminate()));
```

This basically starts the `yes` command which continuously outputs  this

```
y
y
y
y
... (and so on)
```

And then reads only one line from the output of `yes`, and then terminates the process 5 seconds later.

I ran this command while watching `top`, and the result is 5 seconds of `yes` taking 100% CPU, after which it quits. This clearly shows that `yes` does not merely print out one line and then halt or quit.

Even closing the `stdout` read channel (which ignores the rest of the output of `yes`) still doesn't pause the `yes` execution.

You could try [pausing](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/4710-Pause-executing-QProcess) the `QProcess` periodically until you have enough time to process the buffer, but that could get messy.

Answer (score 1):

When you call start() on QProcess, it executes the zcat program, as it does in a terminal. This is a separate process from your Qt program, so it's free to run independently from your Qt application, or in the case of the code you've provided, it will run until it is terminated 10 seconds later.

Whether or not you choose for your application to read the output from zcat is up to you, but it will still continue to run.

Also note that calling process->readline() straight afterwards is probably not the best way of handling the process as your program may try to read the output stream before any data is ready. Instead, you should either call waitForReadyRead() before readline(), or connect a slot to readyRead() signal of QProcess and call readline from that slot.

---- EDITED -----
Based on the change to the question: -

I think you're missing the point of the pipe command. As I understand it, all of the file will be decompressed by zcat, but its output is redirected to the head command. The head command only displays the first number of lines of a file, which is why you only see the first part.

This is like having a file test.txt and calling the command: -

```
cat test.txt | head
```

The whole file exists, but head will only display the first number of lines.

Comment: In practice I have been using `waitForReadyRead()` or the similar signals emitted, but for clarity's sake in the question I left these out since they seemed to distract from the intent of the question. Seems that instead their omission has distracted from the intent of the question. ;)

Comment: Ha ha, no problem, but does it answer your question as to what happens?

Comment: Your answer is helpful, and it provides different information than is available in my answer, but I think the question still remains unanswered. The question title reads "Use QProcess to only zcat as many lines as needed?", and maybe I just need to restate that in the question body.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that from the question as your last statement asks if the process will run line by line, or continue for 10 seconds. Perhaps you should edit the question, or open a new one asking how to process only some lines, though you could try pausing the process as soon as you get some data in readyRead and continue if you want more.

Comment: Yes, the question was definitely un-clear. I was using those last questions to clarify my problem, not as the main question for the problem. I have updated the question.

Comment: I've added an edit to the answer for the edit to your question.

Comment: Your edit is incorrect. `cat test.txt | head` will not necessarily `cat` the entire `test.txt`. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85755/4143).

Comment: If you're referring to the pipe's buffer capacity, that's does not invalidate what I've answered. If this is not what you're referring to, please explain.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35086/discussion-between-merlin069-and-cory-klein)